# Xcode link with label

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, hyperlink

I want to create hyperlink like in html `<a href="...">text</a>`. Is it possible to hyperlink a label in Xcode?

Comment: Not out of the box. You need a UITextField for that, but if you disable user interaction, it is almost the same. Does this help?

Comment: Be a little more specific. Do you need a portion of the label hyperlinked or the entire label?

Comment: I meant a UITextView. Heres a link to the docs:[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html)

Comment: What is your goal? What is the point of the link? Do you want it to act like a button or simply display like a traditional hyperlink?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a tapGestureRecognizer to that label

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.theLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;//Since by default, UILabel is not interaction enabled 
    [self.theLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


    //Some where in the code
    -(void)labelTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
```

Comment: Why in the world would you use a gesture recognizer..?

Comment: @vectorquake Your comment would be more useful if you offered a better suggestion. Don't put down someone's suggested solution unless you can explain why it is a bad idea or offer a better idea. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a custom button with just text?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `Round Rect Button` then setting the background image to be an image that is the same color as your view's background.